# Can we tag a function with time in Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

In Solidity (Ethereum), we can tag a function with a time so it would not be invoked after the time passes. I'm wondering if we can have this mechanism in hyperledger fabric.

**Question**: Does hyperledger fabric support timing? Can we get the current time (e.g. the head block timestamp)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you certainly can find the transaction timestamp, you can find relevant information here: [interface.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/78e18d179c29e5182594a0fa27dc8d5accdb8ead/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L189) and [fabric doc's](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetTxTimestamp)